# Inotifywait Command Taking Too Long to Monitor Directory for Deletion Events

Tags: linux, command-line

My specific use case involves using `inotifywait` to monitor three directories for file deletion events (get the last deleted file time stamp from three directories). The command I'm using is as follows:
These directories contain multiple files that may be increased from time to time.

```
root@1f6335fd9696:~# time inotifywait -q --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' -e DELETE "/data/out/priority.images/" --format "%T %w%f"
2023-10-18 15:41:59 JST /data/out/priority.images/USB_Cam1.jpg
real 0m3.070s
user 0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s

root@1f6335fd9696:~# time inotifywait -q --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' -e DELETE "/data/out/priority.texts/" --format "%T %w%f"
2023-10-18 15:42:24 JST /data/out/priority.texts/USB_Cam1.tgz
real 0m12.521s
user 0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s

root@1f6335fd9696:~# time inotifywait -q --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' -e DELETE "/data/out/videos/" --format "%T %w%f"
2023-10-18 15:42:52 JST /data/out/videos/USB_Cam1.mp4


real 0m13.852s
user 0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
root@1f6335fd9696:~#
```

While the command effectively monitors the directory for deletion events, I've noticed that it can sometimes take longer than expected to respond to these events. This delay is causing some performance issues in my workflow.

If you have any suggestions, insights, related to optimizing `inotifywait` for efficient monitoring of file deletion events, I'd greatly appreciate your input. Any tips or guidance on improving the time performance of this command would be invaluable to me.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Have you consider using `auditd` and use script to browse the logs?

Comment: The output of `time` tells us nothing because e.g. if a file is removed 13.8s after starting `intotifywait` and the tool reacts *immediately*, `time` will tell you `real 0m13.852s` or so. The real test is like `touch /data/out/priority.images/test.foo; time inotifywait -q --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' -e DELETE "/data/out/priority.images/" --format "%T %w%f" & sleep 1; rm /data/out/priority.images/test.foo`. Is the real time substantially longer than 1s? My point is each of your `inotifywait` actually *waits* for the next deletion to occur.

Comment: If this is the culprit, a solution is to run `inotifywait -m` in the background and process the output to pick the last event. E.g. `touch recent; inotifywait -q --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z' -m -e DELETE --format "%T %w%f" dirA dirB dirC | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line" >recent.new && mv recent.new recent; done &` will monitor `dirA`, `dirB` and `dirC` and atomically update `recent`. At any time `cat recent` will show you the last event (if there was at least one). Is this what you want?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, is there need to invent the wheel? As I mention in first comment `auditd` will monitor constantly these operations and sample script will report the results from logs.

Comment: @RomeoNinov If the user really wants to "get the last deleted file time stamp from three directories" and if "improving the time performance" is the goal, then parsing a log on demand to find the last event is not a good way because it takes time that depends on the size of the log. `cat recent` is better, picking the last event has already been done in the background. It's possible to feed `recent` from a log in the background. Does `auditd` provide such (or similar) functionality? I genuinely don't know. Does it? If not then some "wheel" has to be invented (or at least applied) here anyway.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, check https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch , key `-te` option `recent`. So 10 minutes back. And repeat the search every 10 minutes